# Apply Transformation to Request

Tags: fiddler

I'm documenting some work I did toward achieving a desirable SOAP request message. I'm showing how the request evolves over a number of program and configuration changes. After each change, I grab the message from fiddler, but each time, I need to repeat some number of steps:

1. Remove bulky ciphers
2. Remove cleartext username/passwords
3. ...

Is there a way to have fiddler apply such rules for a given request?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler can modify any byte of the request or response, so if you can define exactly what you need to do, then yes, Fiddler can do it for you automatically, using either the script engine or the .NET-based extension model.

Without specific details, of course, it's not likely that anyone can help you with a more specific answer.